# How to migrate only a especific range of scripts using flyway?

Tags: gradle, flyway

I'm using flyway and gradle to make my migrations. Now, i need to migrate only a especific range of scripts in my repository. Is this possible?

Example: my repository has 500 scripts (V1 until V500), but i want to migrate, only V10 until V18).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Baseline at 10, and migrate with target 18

Answer (score 0):

Axel's answer is the correct one. If it somehow doesn't work for you, you can bypass flyway functionality and play with flyway.locations or rename the scripts you don't want to be executed (e.g. by adding a "_" prefix). Not recommended though.